# will_paginate undefined method. The Will_paginate gem appears to work though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I'm using rails 2.3.8

my error:

```
undefined method `will_paginate' for #<ActionView::Base:0x1124bfa10>
```

in environment.rb:

```
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require(:default)
```

in my Gemfile:

```
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.14"
```

in the view:

```
<%= will_paginate(@subscriptions) %>
```

in the controller:

```
@search = Subscription.search(params[:search])
@search.order ||= :ascend_by_account_id

@subscriptions = @search.all.paginate(:include => :account, :page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

Now... will paginate methods appear to work in the rest of the app... it's just that this will_paginate method that is supposed to include pagination links doesn't work. =\

Now, I just started using bundler, and before bundler, everything worked all the time.
in my environment.rb I do

```
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require(:default)
```

right before the `Rails::Initializer` call

and here is the :default part of my gem file:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"
# system
gem "rails", "2.3.8"
gem "activesupport", "2.3.8", :require => "active_support"
gem "rake", "0.8.7"

# might be for POW, not sure
gem "childprocess", "0.2.2", :git => "git://github.com/jarib/childprocess.git"


# app
gem "mysql", "2.7"
gem "lockfile"
gem "ssl_requirement", "0.1.0"
gem "attr_encrypted", "1.1.2"
#gem "searchlogic", "2.5.6"
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.16"
gem "paperclip"


gem "garb", "0.7.6"
gem "delayed_job", "2.0.3"
gem "httparty", "0.5.2"


gem "pony", "1.1"
gem "friendly_id", "3.0.6"
gem "stringex", "1.1.0"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"

gem "sms_fu", "1.1.1"
```

NOTE: for some reason search logic only works when it's included in the Rails:Initializer.run call in classic rails 2.3 way., config.gem "searchlogic", :version => "2.2.28"

Comment: What happens if you take the :include => :account out? Does the paginate statement run? Just everything I've seen on a quick Google suggests if there's something weird going on with the model it'll occasionally go a bit weird.

Comment: yeah, that didn't change anything. What's weird is this all worked before I switched over to bundle.

Comment: Huh, so pre-bundler it worked and still works in some parts of your app?

Comment: correct, and I'm i'll add to my question about how I'm including things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the auto-requiring of will_paginate:

```
# Gemfile
gem "will_paginate", "~> 2.3.15", :require => nil
```

And require it yourself, manually, at the end of environment.rb:

```
# end of environment.rb
require "will_paginate"
```

The thing is, if you require will_paginate before the `Rails::Initializer` call, it might not boostrap properly.

Comment: should I do that with Bundler.require? like... just have all my gems after the initializer?

Comment: that worked by the way. thanks! but now I just need to find a solution for search logic. I posted a question about that one, too. The situation is a bit different.