# will_paginate 'stack level too deep'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Continuation of:

[undefined method `will_paginate', Rails 3.1 / DataMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418061/undefined-method-will-paginate-rails-3-1-datamapper)

placing

= will_paginate @collection_of_objects

anywhere in my template but at the top generates

```
stack level too deep
Extracted source (around line #):
```

error.

Why? Having to put the pager only at the top of a template is unacceptable. It doesn't work in a partial either (same message).

Comment: What is your collection ? is it the response of a paginate call of your model in the controller ? I guess that your collection references the paginated collection itself and may cause `the stack level too deep error`. but if it works at the top of the page, it's still strange...

Comment: `stack level too deep` usually means there's an infinite loops going on. please show code & route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just released will_paginate 3.0.3 with a bunch of DataMapper fixes.